# How do I switch back to windows booting up after installing Mavericks?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, osx-mavericks

I have an Intel based Mac.  For the longest time, I was running just Windows 7 on the computer because I had no need for a Mac OS (I of course am not the one who bought it).  Then I just recently installed Mavericks on a fresh hard drive on the computer and everytime I turn on the computer it boots into Mavericks instead of Windows 7.  Is there at least some keyboard combination which would allow me to choose which OS to boot on?

I have heard about Boot Camp, but I get the impression that you install Windows after the fact.

So how do I get my Windows to boot up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is when you hear the apple chime or logo you press down the option key and choose windows. This startup volume selection is temporary.  To set the default startup volume for your Mac after your computer is running, open System Preferences and choose Startup Disk from the View menu (in Mac OS X) and set what you want.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that.  The option key was what I was after.  The other part will inevitably be helpful in the future too.  Thanks.